# How to put my data from a table using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I know this question has been asked multiple times but looking through and trying the solutions has not got me far.

I would like the table to have a format of:

```
First name | Last Name
Mike         Hannover
Steve        Dortmund
```

however I am not sure how to achieve this, it currently lays out like as I have taken the table coding out that I have tried.

```
FirstName: Mike - LastName: Hannover
FirstName: Steven - LastName: Dortmund
```

I have attached my PHP code below and thanks in advance for your time and help.

```
<body>
<h1>Clients information</h1>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "lastgo";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM info";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "FirstName: " . $row["FirstName"]. " 
- LastName: " . $row["LastName"].  "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Can you please format your question?

Comment: Sorry, @ShaifulIslam just corrected it now!

Comment: You want the names in separate lines or in just one line?

Comment: What table coding? You have no `<table>`-related tags at all.

Comment: @MarcB yes sorry I took them out for this question as every one I tried was not working :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easier way is to build your table is to do it as a table.

```
// Just looking at this part of the code.
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // Begin a table
  echo "<table>";
  // Create a header row
  echo "<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>";
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     // output data for each row
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["FirstName"]. "</td><td>" .       
    $row["LastName"]. "</td></tr>";
  }
  // Close table
  echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: That's the one! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand you want to print your FirstnName and LastName like so

Change your while loop to:

```
 echo "<table>";
 echo "<th>FirstName: </th><th>LastName</th>";   
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     echo "<tr>".
              "<td>" .$row["FirstName"] ."</td>"
             ."<td>" . $row["LastName"]."</td>
           .</tr>>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a table, then style it the way you want the records to appear

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($names as $value) : ?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $value['Name']; ?></td><td><?php echo $value['LastName']; ?></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

[image]